# Fresh ubuntu 18.04 won't play videos

Tags: nvidia, 18.04, video, vlc

I cannot reproduce videos in browser or in vlc. I can see a screenshot of the video, and I can forward and preview the video but it won't play.

I have installed following packages:

```
sudo apt install libdvdnav4 libdvdread4 gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly libdvd-pkg

sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras

sudo apt install vlc
```

Moreover, I have another computer (exact same hardware) , did a fresh installation and it is working

Comment: did you run all your updates after install? also, you might want to try updating video drivers via the PPA `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa && sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade && sudo apt dist-upgrade` and the maybe try selecting the 390 pro driver in Software & Updates -> Additional drivers